# How is the output of this printf() statement computed?

Tags: c, binary, printf, operators, output

```
  int x = 3 > 4; 
  int y = 4.98;

  printf("%d %d\n", x && y, x || y);
```

output:

```
 0  1
```

My work:

For x variable:  Since 3 > 4 is false... in C that means it returns 0 since 0 means false in C and true means 1    =>  x = 0

For y variable:  Since y is an integer and a decimal is given then y is instantly downcasted to 4   => y=4

Binary of 0 is 0000

Binary of 4 is 0100

So

```
x && y = 0000 && 0100 = 0000

x || y = 0000 || 0100 = 0100 != 0001 (??)
```

Why does x || y = 1?

Comment: && and || are logical operators and not bitwise operators

Comment: Your answer would have been right for `printf("%d %d\n", x & y, x | y);` To "visualize" `||` and `&&` you can add implicit `!= 0` to each side.

Comment: True in C means anything different from zero (0).
Also you need to understand better about operators precedence in C, is is quite important to understand how operators are evaluated by the compiler.
Please refer to this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) to understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing logical and bitwise operators. `&&` Just means 'and', and `||` just means or. Since y is not 0, it's considered true, and since x is 0, it's false, so `x && y` is zero because x is false and `x || y` is 1 because y is true.

Maybe what you're thinking of is bitwise operators. Bitwise and is just `&`, and bitwise or is just `|`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Answer (score 1):

&& operator will check both the inputs, if both inputs are true or 1 then it will return 1 else it will return false or 0.
Where as || operator will check if any of the input is true or 1 then it will return 1 else it will return false or 0. Eg

`1 || 0  ->  1 
 1 && 0  ->  0`

In you code after computation

`x = 0
y = 4
0 && 4  ->  0
0 || 4  ->  1`

Comment: As per your answer " if both inputs are true or 1 then it will return 1 else it will return false or 0". How could 0 || 4 be 1 since 4 is not true nor 1 also?

Comment: || is a conditional-OR operator it will OR two inputs and if the result is greater than 0 then it will return 1 else it will return 0 eg binary of 1 is 1 and of 4 is 100 so 001 OR 100 will give 101 which is 5 so it will return 1.

Answer (score 0):

False evaluates to 0, but anything different from 0 is true (`true != false` == `true != 0`)

And you're using logical operators. If you want bitwise operators they're `&` (and), `|` (or) and `^` (xor)

Answer (score 0):

`&&` and `||` are logical operators and not bitwise operators.

`0` is considered to be false and any other value is considered to be true in logical operations.

`x || y`, which is `0 || 4`, implies `false || true`.

`||` is the logical `OR` operator. So `false || true` turns out to be true.

More on this here - http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Logical-Operators.